# SQL query - how to fetch non-read messages efficiently

Tags: sql

How do I best gather messages that have not been read by a given user?

Existing tables

```
Message table
----------------------------------
id    title    body    sentAt

User table
----------------------------------
id    username

Read Messages table
----------------------------------
user_id    message_id
```

I'm thinking something like

```
select 
  m.id, m.title, m.sentAt, u.username
from 
  message m,
  [user] u
where 
  u.id = 1 and -- @userId parameter
  m.id not in 
    (select r.message_id from read_messages r where r.user_id = u.id)
```

Unfortunately for me I dont understand much looking at the execution plan. /Adam

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Suggesting an alternative approach:*

I was faced with the exact same problem at work earlier. I wasted a good week in trying to figure the best way to do this. I ended up with creating a join table, as you have done, but the table contains only *unread* messages, instead of keeping track of *read* messages.

## Because

1. The status quo is "everyone has read all their messages".
2. Getting the unread messages (or their count) should be as fast as possible.
3. The status quo should be the least straining status on the system.

Now, if I would've kept track of all the messages everyone has read, the clutter in the database grows pretty rapidly (*users***messages* rows), easily leading to thousands of rows of 'dead weight' in even smaller applications. This problem is exaggerated if the lifetime of messages are indefinite - you could be keeping track of message statuses that are many years old.

If keeping track of the inverse, your "unread messages" table contains only a handful of rows, and they diminish for each message that a user reads. Also, getting the amount of unread messages is as simple as "`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM unread WHERE user = foo`".

## But

As everything, this is a trade-off. While reading is pretty much as fast as computationally possible, writing is a chore. For each written message, you need to insert an entry to this join table. Additionally, if multiple people can read the same message, you need to insert one row for each recipient. If the recipients are implicit (e.g. only a user group's name is given, or even with the criteria such as "anyone who has access to this thing"), creating new messages becomes even more complicated.

But I feel this is a fair compromise.

YMMV, HTH.

Comment: I've been reading your post a few times and the more I think about it... it is a better fit for my scenario. 

Thanks for a comprehensive post!

Comment: Isn't saving the last seen message time the best idea. When we want to calculate the unread message we can just check the count of the message after that time.

Answer (score 3):

NOT IN is very expensive. Instead, you could do something like:

```
SELECT
  m.id, m.title, m.sentAt
FROM
  message m
  LEFT JOIN [Read Messages] rm
    ON m.message_id = rm.message_id AND rm.user_id = @userID
WHERE
  rm.user_id IS NULL
```

Provided you have the right indexes, this should be much faster.

You're fetching all messages and LEFT JOINing read messages for that user. Then, in the WHERE clause you're asking for that user_id to be NULL for that message, meaning the user has not read it yet.

Comment: Is it that much a difference between this and my approach? I think NOT IN is much more readable than a JOIN but I know SQL isn't my strongest suit.

Comment: Yes, there is. NOT IN will get a [possible huge] list of IDs from and then compare each message row with that (similar to WHERE id = X OR id = Y OR OR ...), which is too expensive. My alternative uses indexes so it should be way faster. Anyway, I believe Henrik Paul's solution is better than mine :)

Comment: Isn't saving the last seen message time the best idea. When we want to calculate the unread message we can just check the count of the message after that time.

Comment: @RishabhDhiman The question is to retrieve all unread messages, not just the count.

Comment: @Seb if we have the last read message time can't we get message after that time? Obviously removing count and inserting star will give us the unread messages.

Comment: @RishabhDhiman Yes. But that does not answer the question. It's very common in Stack Overflow that people suggest different way of solving a problem while modifying the premise. Some times that's not possible, maybe because it's a legacy system, or they don't want to update the database tables for some reason, or the code that updates such information. All I'm saying is that saving the last seen message implies modifying the tables AND adding logic to save that info, because the question didn't include those fields.

Answer (score 1):

HP's alternative suggestion is most likely suiting you well. However, if it is not, Id suggest using NOT EXISTS rather than LEFT JOIN if it's possible in your environment.

At least on MS SQL it would give a slightly cheaper query plan, since it would not need the last filtering (user_id IS NULL)

```
SELECT  ...
FROM    message m
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM    read_messages rm
    WHERE   rm.usr_id = ...
    AND rm.msg_id = m.msg_id
)
```